# how to show dynamically nested child array object of an object while nested level is not restricted

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an array of object each object have children property which is also an object, that object have also children property which is also an object which include also children property which is also an object and so on ............

some object have children and some don't have children (i.e children: Array[0])
i want to display them dynamically on single page using dynamic routes. for example first i will show object list then if any object have child then that child will be see on the same page but using different route on button click (i.e., ng-click)

how it is possible
array of object [object, object, object]
hierarchy example for more clarification

```
0: Object
1: Object
       children: Array[3]
           1: Object
           2: Object

2: Object
        children: Array[3]
           1: Object
                   children: Array[3]
                            1: Object

                            2: Object
                            3: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

parent id will be given in each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular UI Tree directive.

https://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

If you want to create custom directive, you can use recursive templating in ng-repeat.

Something like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="children_renderer.html">
{{data.label}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="children in data.childrens" ng-include="'children_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<ul ng-controller="NestedFormCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="child in childData" ng-include="'children_renderer.html'"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: looking fine this ui component but the problem is i want to show one the same page using different route while child is showing his parent\child will not be shown